# neo4j is storing arbitrary files in drive C?

Tags: neo4j

my C Drive size is growing and my server is not running any thing but neo4j. 
even though i configured neo4j to store database information on some other drive.

node count might be irrelevant but for the record, i have almost 10 million nodes and traffic to database about 200 request / minute.

is there any thing else written by neo4j that i should be aware of?

```
dbms.directories.data=E:/MyNeoDB4/
dbms.directories.logs=E:/MyNeoDb4 
dbms.jvm.additional=-Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=zip
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=15
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=15G
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=8G
```

**Update 1:**
things i have checked already:

- my debug log is being written some where other than Drive C
- metrics.enabled=false

**Update 2:**
- as @InverseFalcon said i also checked transaction logs in the first step. they were being written in some other directory.

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: Answer was written before original question was updated to say that neither metrics nor logs were the likely culprits)*

**Logs, and possibly metrics**

I'm not sure what your logging needs have been like, but a major source of disk consumption that is not the data itself is the writing of log files. They typically do not grow extremely quickly, but it totally depends on your set up.

I suspect that your drive may be filling up with logs, although I am surprised it's filling up so quickly. I would check out your log files and see if they are full of long chains of exceptions.

It could also be metrics being exported to CSV on the local disk, although I do not believe that Neo4J will do that without being explicitly configured to do so.

More info on metrics is at the official docs:
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/metrics/

Comment: hi, thanks for quick response. i have update the question. metrics are disabled.

Comment: If it is not either of those, It's possible that it is not coming from Neo4J. Are you able to identify exactly what directories are growing in size? I've found that https://windirstat.net/ is very helpful for that.

Answer (score 0):

A variant on Rebecca Nelson's answer, you might want to check for transaction log files.

Transaction logs are the source of truth for changes made to a database, and they are not the same kinds of logs as the readable log files (debug.log, neo4j.log) that live in the logs folder.

You can find transaction logs in your graph.db folder (or whatever name you've given to your graph database folder) using the naming pattern `neostore.transaction.db.0` (with incremental numbering of the log files starting with 0).

Transaction logs are a stage of data persistence. Transactions affecting the database first write to these logs. When criteria are met, a checkpoint operation occurs which flushes the contents of the transaction logs to the datastore files (some of the other files in the graph.db folder) and the transaction logs are pruned and/or rotated.

While you should not modify or delete transaction log files yourself, you can add configuration parameters in neo4j.conf to control how these files are handled.

Here are the [docs dealing with transaction logs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/transaction-logs/).

Comment: thanks, i checked that also, they were in some other direcotry